# Servicemix Bundle Installation directory

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have a bundle up and running in Servicemix for a long time. I cant even use 'history' to see where this bundle got installed from.

Is there any way I could find where this bundle originally got installed from?

As a note:  this bundle does exist in my company's central repository but I dont see the exact version there. seems like this bundle got installed using File component something like install file:jar_location/jar_name.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a standalone bundle, then try

```
    la -l | grep <bundle_id>
```

This will show the exact installation link. (with protocol as well)
Also it might be just dropped into ${SMX_HOME}/deploy. If you have a simple jar file it can be dropped and got fragmented automatically.

Also I'd check if it's coming from a feature (list the attached feature urls):

```
    features:listurl
```

It's useful to know if you'll have to updat it. See

```
    features:install / features:uninstall
```

Hope that helps,
Gergely

Comment: Although la -l didnt work for me. But I found the bundles here : "/usr/local/servicemix/data/cache/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles" . So I think any bundle which is deployed in servicemix would exist here as well. i used your cmd "ls -l | grep <bundle_id>" after landing to this directory and found it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your welcome. I meant "la -l" inside SMX sorry. It's in it's bash.